# SmptClient "direct replies to" option?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

In Outlook, we have the "Direct replies to" option setting when we compose an email, which is used to override when recipient replies.

Is there any way to do the same through SmtpClient class in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 'ReplyToList' property on the 'MailMessage' class.  The ReplyTo is set on the message, not the SmtpClient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.replytolist.aspx